# Creating new org.joda.time.DateTime Throwing throwing Initialization Error

Tags: java, datetime, initialization, jodatime

My mapreduce job is failing with the cause outlined as:
Full stack:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology.<clinit>(ISOChronology.java:59)
at org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.getChronology(DateTimeUtils.java:266)
at org.joda.time.convert.AbstractConverter.getChronology(AbstractConverter.java:82)
at org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime.<init>(BaseDateTime.java:172)
at org.joda.time.DateTime.<init>(DateTime.java:257)
at com.xxx.myClass(myFile.scala:70)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am calling the constructor from scala:

```
val dateTime: DateTime = new DateTime(long)
```

Comment: `ExceptionInInitializerError` should be listing the *cause*. Please paste in the *full* stacktrace.

Comment: @Andreas the next line is where I called it from in my code:

Comment: And further down there is a "Caused by:" listing the **real** exception. There may be multiple "Caused By". The last one is likely the one you should pay attention to. If you want help (you're here for a reason), we can only help you if you **show us the full stacktrace**.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry about that.. now updated.

Comment: And the call stack of the `NullPointerException` is? ***Show us the FULL stacktrace!!!***